# Order by string returns wrong order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using a column which is named `ItemCode`. `ItemCode` is `Varchar(50)` type.
Here is my query

```
Select * from Inventory order by ItemCode
```

So, now my result is looks like

```
ItemCode-1
ItemCode-10
ItemCode-2
ItemCode-20
```

And so on.
How can I order my string as the example below?

```
ItemCode-1
ItemCode-2
ItemCode-10
ItemCode-20
```

Should I convert my column as number? Also I mention that I have some fields that contain no number.

Comment: Why are you using the word "ItemCode" for each ItemCode? Can't you just use the code (number) alone? It's useless there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, based on [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127644):

> that is lexicographic sorting which means basically the language
>   treats the variables as strings and compares character by character

You need to use something like this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ItemCode like '%[0-9]%' 
THEN Replicate('0', 100 - Len(ItemCode)) + ItemCode
ELSE ItemCode  END
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer to fill with zeros before my string seems to work very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could order by the numbers as

```
SELECT Str
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('ItemCode-1'),
    ('ItemCode-10'),
    ('ItemCode-2'),
    ('ItemCode-20')
) T(Str)
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(Str, LEN(Str) - CHARINDEX('-', Str)) AS INT)
```

Note: Since you tagged your Q with `SQL Server 2008` tag, you should upgrade as soon as possible because it's out of support.

UPDATE:

Since you don't provide a good sample data, I'm just guessing.
Here is another way may feet your requirements

```
SELECT Str
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('ItemCode-1'),
    ('ItemCode-10'),
    ('ItemCode-2'),
    ('ItemCode-20'),
    ('Item-Code')
) T(Str)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Str LIKE '%[0-9]' THEN CAST(RIGHT(Str, LEN(Str) - CHARINDEX('-', Str)) AS INT) ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you Sami, unfortunately when i have a field which is totally string, without containing any number, i am getting exception Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '940Β' to data type int.